# Are there any plans for Java to add implicit Getters and Setters?

Tags: java, getter-setter, language-design

Does anyone know if there is a plan to add in implicit getters and setters for Class variables?

I'm thinking of the current Scala code that allows this already.  Something like the following, where if you don't define a getter/setter it uses the value, but if you do define a getter/setter for the value it uses that instead of a direct variable call.

```
class A{
    int value = 3;
}

class B{
    int value = 3;
    public int value(){
        return value;
    }
}

// in some method
A a = new A();
System.out.println(a.value); 
B b = new B();
System.out.println(b.value); // <-- no () for accessing value even though it uses the getter
```

Comment: It’s done. Preview in 15. https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359

Answer (score 9, accepted):

not Java per se, but there is this [Project Lombok](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/42946)

Comment: If the annotations are at compile time, how do you write the getter?  can you give an example?  Also is Lombok required when you run the jar or is this all compile time?

Comment: Lombox installs as an Eclipse plugin, so the getters and setters are available in the IDE.  Have a look at http://projectlombok.org/ , http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJan2010.html#installation and http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJan2010.html#gettersetter

Answer (score 4):

**Foreword:** maybe I'm wrong but the question is maybe a better fit for java platform user/devel lists, like those at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/community/index.html

I suppose you'll receive more meaningful answers there, and less speculation.

My own take on the subject is that the *JavaBean* model is far too established to admit any significant change for backward compatibility, and that java encapsulation model is based on the concept that you hide fields with private access and provide *accessors/mutators*.

If you only want to expose members you can simply make them *public*.

Translating fields to automatic *accessor/mutator* methods is quite a big change to the  language, and would probably create much confusion for little gain.

You should also consider that the scala choice implies a radically different approach to member access, for the sake of [uniform access principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle).

Comment: Making them just public isn't a great solution so for now I'll deal with the code bloat. But hopefully one day they will come around (despite the possible massive code change).

Answer (score 0):

A simple getter returns a field value. However a getter can also return the results of an operation:

```
public boolean isError()
{
   return errorList.size() > 0;
}
```

Similarly a setter might do other operations:

```
public void setName(String name)
{
   this.name = name;
   this.sortName = name.toLowerCase();
}
```

So other than the bean paradigm, and for the sake of consistency, getters/setters should be used rather than direct field access.

Answer (score 0):

Java 14 (LTS release) has records, but you need to compile with additional options for it to work. Records provide getters for the constructor params and aim to solve a few other problems inherent in earlier versions.

Comment: So implicit getters but no implicit setters? Seems like a huge design failure to leave that out. What the hell were they thinking? BTW maybe it should have been one, but I'm pretty sure 14 isn't an LTS release, unless there's some rogue JDK vendor still supporting it.

Comment: Oh.. according to this, the fields are final. https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359 I guess scope is a bit narrower than the concept the OP here is asking about... still seems a little too conservative.